# fixed rtl direction in tcpdf in all pages

Tags: php, tcpdf, right-to-left

i have a problem with TCPDF library ,i'm generating pdf file usind TCPDF library in arabic language,the file direction is rtl so i used **$pdf->setRTL(true);** , and every thing is fine  in the first page ,put in the second page or third the direction reseted to ltr!!!

this is apice of my code:

```
$pdf->AddPage();

$l = Array();
$l['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$l['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$l['a_meta_language'] = '';
$l['w_page'] = '';
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->SetFont('almohanad', '', 16);
$pdf->setRTL(true); // cehck here if ar or en



$html = '
  <style>
    html{
      direction:rtl;
    }
  </style>

  <div style="direction:rtl">  
    <br/><br/>
    <img src="' . $image . '" />
    <br/>
    <span style="color:green">'.$date.'</span>
    <h5 style="color:gray">'.$title.'</h5>
    <div style="color:blue;direction:rtl">'.$content.'</div>
  </div>
';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, true, "");
$pdf->setRTL(true);
$pdf->lastPage();
#excute the file
$pdf->Output($fileName, 'I');
```

So my question is: how can I make all pages in tcpdf have the same direction as rtl ???

Answer (score 7):

This problem was fixed by Iranians in the TCPDF Class. 
Download TCPDF from http://www.tcpdf.org/

 and run `example_018.php` in examples

```
//Before Write
// set some language dependent data:
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

//After Write
$pdf->setRTL(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// set some language dependent data:
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 12);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Persian and English content
$htmlpersian = '<span color="#660000">Persian example:</span><br />سلام بالاخره مشکل PDF فارسی به طور کامل حل شد. اینم یک نمونش.<br />مشکل حرف \"ژ\" در بعضی کلمات مانند کلمه ویژه نیز بر طرف شد.<br />نگارش حروف لام و الف پشت سر هم نیز تصحیح شد.<br />با تشکر از  "Asuni Nicola" و محمد علی گل کار برای پشتیبانی زبان فارسی.';
$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlpersian, true, 0, true, 0);

// set LTR direction for english translation
$pdf->setRTL(false);

$pdf->SetFontSize(10);

// print newline
$pdf->Ln();

// Persian and English content
$htmlpersiantranslation = '<span color="#0000ff">Hi, At last Problem of Persian PDF Solved completely. This is a example for it.<br />Problem of "jeh" letter in some word like "ویژه" (=special) fix too.<br />The joining of laa and alf letter fix now.<br />Special thanks to "Nicola Asuni" and "Mohamad Ali Golkar" for Persian support.</span>';
$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlpersiantranslation, true, 0, true, 0);

// Restore RTL direction
$pdf->setRTL(true);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('aefurat', '', 18);
```